# Linker error when enabling Link Time Optimization in NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, clang++

When I add the flag `-flto` to my NDK C++ project the linker emits the following error: "Optimization level must be between 0 and 3", even though my optimization level is explicitly set to 3 via `-O3.`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

The compiler flags are passed via Gradle which, as I understand it, should pass the flags to both the Clang compiler and linker. When I remove the `-flto` flag everything works fine.

*Notes:*

- I'm using NDK 19.2 (latest version at the time I write this).
- I also get the warning `"clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Wa,--noexecstack' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]"` which I do not have if I compile without link time optimizations.

Comment: Okay, I might be really stupid, I suppose between 0 and 3 means 1 or 2 :)

Comment: How are you setting `-O3`?

Comment: Via gradle as well, it seems weird to me that flto and O3  would not be compatible

Comment: But how? What are you typing? What variable are you changing?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I've put the relevant native build config in this file: http://toppluva.com/misc/gradle_flto.txt The only build parameter is -flto in the gradle part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts to the answer:

The error is caused by https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/721. Clang's LTO plugin just doesn't accept `-Os` or `-Oz`. This is a bug.

> Okay, I might be really stupid, I suppose between 0 and 3 means 1 or 2 :)

It's actually because you can't use the generic `cppFlags` to set optimization levels. That corresponds to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, and you need to set these in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` (and/or the C flavors of those). CMake has its own defaults in those variables and the command line is built as `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}`, so your `-O3` is being overridden by the default.

Comment: Thank you, it works! If anyone else is struggling with this (and does not master CMake), add set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O3 -flto=full") to you CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter this linking error but I fixed through a different way.

I had cross-compile a library for android with architectures of both arm64 and armv7. It's all OK for arm64 but encounter the linking error for armv7. And I found it can be fixed by commented out the following statements in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION} GREATER_EQUAL 3 AND ${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION} GREATER_EQUAL 9)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0069 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069 NEW)
  include(CheckIPOSupported)
  check_ipo_supported(RESULT ipo_supported OUTPUT ipo_supported_output)
  if (ipo_supported)
    set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
  endif ()
endif ()
```

The above CMake statements are related to the IPO setting and it seems cause the linking error when cross-compiling for android armv7.

I don't know why the IPO should not enabled for android armv7.